# Frequencies - From fft to file to list using processing

Tags: processing, fft

I'm doing a project where I'm outputting the frequencies from real time mic input through fft to a txt doc and then retrieving (or trying to retrieve) them to a list of 4 frequencies. My list array is turning out empty, ie the console prints [] and no numbers in them. Pl tell me what is wrong with the logic/code. This is within the void draw()

```java
for (int i = 0; i<fft.specSize(); i++) {

float freq = fft.getFreq(i);
int freqint = (int) freq;
//println(freqint);
output.println(freqint);}



 Scanner input = new Scanner("...\\list.txt");





while (input.hasNextInt()) {
    list.get(input.nextInt(4));

}




println(list);


input.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Split your taks into subtasks:

1. get FFT data (and 4 frequencies)
2. Save/Load float values to disk
3. Put the 1 and 2 together

It looks like you already have the first part done.
It's unclear what the 4 frequencies are, but you can figure that out on your own.

The part that is confusing is that you call the get FFT data once then try to save it straight to disk. I'm not 100% that's what you mean to do.
Double check if you need to save few samples/seconds worth of FFT data first.

I would imagine a more generic scenario like this:

1. load previously saved FFT data (if any)
2. process FFT data (for as long as needed - might need a start/stop boolean) and append
3. save current FFT data

Moving on to saving and loading data.
You've got a few of options build into Processing for storing data:

1. Strings via [saveStrings()](https://processing.org/reference/saveStrings_.html)/[loadStrings()](https://processing.org/reference/loadStrings_.html)
2. CSV Table via [saveTable()](https://processing.org/reference/saveTable_.html)/[loadTable()](https://processing.org/reference/loadTable_.html)/[Table](https://processing.org/reference/Table.html)
3. JSON via [JSONObject](https://processing.org/reference/JSONObject.html)/[JSONArray](https://processing.org/reference/JSONArray.html) and available load/save functions
4. [XML](https://processing.org/reference/XML.html)

I recommend reading [Daniel Shiffman's Data Tutorial](https://processing.org/tutorials/data/)

Dealing with saving/loading floating point values to disk alone,
here's a basic proof of concept snippet using Strings:

```
int fftSpecSize = 10;//this will be fft.specSize() in your case

String values = "";

for(int i = 0 ; i < fftSpecSize; i++){
  //random(1) is a placeholder for fft.getFreq(i);
  values += random(1);
  //if it's not the last value, add a separator character (in this case space)
  if(i < fftSpecSize-1){
    values += " ";
  }
}

println("values to save:");
println(values);
println();
//save data
saveStrings("fftSingleRead.txt",values.split(" "));

//load data
String[] readValues = loadStrings("fftSingleRead.txt");

//print raw loaded data
println("readValues from .txt file:");
println(readValues);
println();

//parse values:
for(int i = 0 ; i < readValues.length; i++){
  float value = float(readValues[i]);
  println("readValues[",i,"] = ",value);
}
```

additionally here's a Table example too:

```
Table fftValues;
int specSize = 10;

//create a new table
fftValues = new Table();
//add columns - one per FFT bin
for(int i = 0 ; i < specSize; i++){
  fftValues.addColumn();
}

//add some data, a row per reading
//create a new row
TableRow newRow = fftValues.addRow();
//add each fft value to the row
for(int fftCount = 0 ; fftCount < specSize; fftCount++){
  //placeholder for newRow.setFloat(fftCount,fft.getFreq(fftCount));
  newRow.setFloat(fftCount,random(1));
}
//add the row to the table
fftValues.addRow(newRow);

//save to disk
saveTable(fftValues,"fftValues.csv","csv");

//load from disk
Table readValues = loadTable("fftValues.csv","csv");
//access the data that has been saved in the table
for(int rowCount = 0; rowCount < readValues.getRowCount(); rowCount++){
  TableRow currentRow = readValues.getRow(rowCount);
  print("row[",rowCount,"] = ");
  for(int columnCount = 0; columnCount < currentRow.getColumnCount(); columnCount++){

    float value = currentRow.getFloat(columnCount); 

    print(value);

    if(columnCount < currentRow.getColumnCount() - 1){
      print(",");
    }
  }
  println();
}
```

Try the code, see the output, read the comments, read the reference, tweak/retry/understand and adapt to your problem.

Comment: What I had intended to do was to get the first four or five frequencies after fft. That's all. But to do that, I had to do a circuitous write to a txt file and then use scanner as scanner takes only string or file. When I run, the txt file does record the frequencies in int, and almost the first 800 to 1000 numbers are 0 and then only other numbers such as 1 or 11 or 14 or whatever the real time input from mic gathers gets in.

Comment: Pl also check my second post that is displayed after my first post itself. I thought it will be displayed after yours.

Comment: Tried your code. On the first instance, it works and I think reads/saves the first ten frequencies. Will understand it more elaborately and adapt to my problem as you mentioned.

Comment: Deleted my post as it seemed redundant.

Comment: Now, how do I save the first few frequencies, ie, first 10 or 20? I get the frequencies through fft.getFreq(I) in the for loop or the random placeholder for freq as in your code. I just want to sit the first few frequencies still in a txt file or even println to the console. If I try to take the frequencies out of the for loop through a variable or list , I get null list. I'm stuck there.

Comment: Please make your intentions as clear as possible: this will help you achieve your goal as well, while enabling others to help you ?

Comment: First get the FFT data you're after, then worry about storing it. Check out [this minim FFT sample](https://github.com/ddf/Minim/blob/master/examples/Analysis/SoundSpectrum/SoundSpectrum.pde)